# How to make 'Clear Slicers' Code More Efficient?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm working with six slicers on a summary sheet in Excel 2010. Each slicer is connected to 26 pivot tables.

I used the code below in the past to clear slicer selections and it worked with minimal lag. This time the code takes 6-7 seconds to execute.

```
Dim oSlicerC As SlicerCache

For Each oSlicerC In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    oSlicerC.ClearManualFilter
Next oSlicerC
```

I can't find anything online to speed up the macro/make it more efficient.

I tried setting `ScreenUpdating`, `DisplayAlerts`, and `EnableEvents` to `False` and I tried setting `Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of my code.

I thought about iterating through each `SlicerItem` to de-select each one, but with up to 100 items in a few slicers I'm not sure that would be any faster.

I'm not looking for code as I'd like to take a stab at it myself, but I'm not sure which path I should take or if there's even a more efficient alternative to what I'm already using.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, settled on:

```
Dim oSlicerC As SlicerCache
For Each oSlicerC In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
If oSlicerC.FilterCleared = False Then oSlicerC.ClearManualFilter
Next oSlicerC`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've never seen `.FilterCleared` before. Without testing, I don't think this resolves my issue because the long runtime is due to the number of items and pivots each slicer is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but there is also another possibility.

If you have the data in an excel table you can call on that table

```
tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

This will also reset all slicers very fast.

with 173'561 rows and **other things in between my program**.

for each example above: 6.88 sec
my example: 6.92 sec

Perhaps there are situation where one or the other is faster.
e.g. it has to reset more than just a few slicers my version should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

i see it was posted long ago, but still this could be usefull:
i just defined 2 parameters for sliceritems, and while looping on first items, ran another loop to unselect all.
'''

```
For Each oSi In oScR.SlicerItems
    If oSi.HasData Then
        For Each oSiT In oScR.SlicerItems:
            If oSiT.HasData Then oSiT.Selected = False
        Next
        oSi.Selected = True

    End If
Next
```

'''